# values passed to the '_id' (mongodb) is not a valid ObjectId Pymongo

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I have a python script that receive (from a node.js script) an **_id** for a mongodb document as an argument. Using that value I'm trying to query the db and retrieve a document.

However, when i try to run the script it throws an error saying

> *"'xxxxxxxxxx' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string".*

**my script where the error is causing:**

```
result = db.req.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(sys.argv[1])})
```

When i check the `type()` of the `sys.argv[1]` it says `str`. I thought wrapping the string around `ObjectId` should do the trick.

value of `sys.argv[1]` when printed: '"5902fbdd4d2f430dfe2dded4"'

Anyone one know whats the reason causing the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you printed it out to see what the value of `sys.argv[1]` is?

Comment: give us example of your string object

Comment: Hi, this is the value that comes up in the error log for the argument passed in '"5902fbdd4d2f430dfe2dded4"'

Comment: maybe it should be `5902fbdd4d2f430dfe2dded4 ` not `"5902fbdd4d2f430dfe2dded4"`, I think you should not add `"`

Comment: Hi im not adding the ". for some reason when the value is passed from node.js script its added. i do JSON.stringify(data._id) in node.js before passing it to python.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I removed the JSON.stringify() bit from the passing value in the node.js script. All seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB allows storing "_id" in "ObjectId" format.